# How to get arguments which were used when the layer was created?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Suppose I use `VGG19`:

```
tf.keras.applications.VGG19().summary()
```

And I'd like to know additional information about the penultimate layer:

```
_________________________________________________________________
fc2 (Dense)                  (None, 4096)              16781312  
_________________________________________________________________
```

I mean how can I get all the arguments which were used in this layer? Keras documentation specify the following arguments for `Dense` layer:

```
keras.layers.Dense(units, activation=None, use_bias=True, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform',
bias_initializer='zeros', kernel_regularizer=None, bias_regularizer=None, activity_regularizer=None,
kernel_constraint=None, bias_constraint=None)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `model.layers[-1].get_config()` to get all the parameters of the layer.